# Putting a hidden column in WebGrid MVC3

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to put some hidden columns in the Webgrid. there a few key columns in my output which are not to be shown to the users but I need them to be present in the webgrid. I require these columns in the grid because when a user selects the row in the grid and clicks on modify I need those keys to get the details of selected columns.Can you please tell me how can I have a hidden column in the webgrid?(razor vb.net syntax please)

Answer (score 0):

See Bianca Huluban's answer posted here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1750407.aspx/1

```
@{
    Dim grid As New WebGrid(Model)

    @grid.GetHtml( _
        columns:= grid.Columns(grid.Column( _
            null, _
            null, _
            format: @<input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="@item.Id"/>))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put hidden column inside the S.No. column

```
grid.Column(header: "S.No.", format: @<text> <div> @(item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item) + 1) <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" /> </div> </text>),
```

enjoy this will not show the column space also